# MySQL Full Text search increase relevance for exact matches?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, mariadb

I have a MySQL database of ~10,000 organisation names that I want to be able to search. I would like to use a full text search because this would enable me to find "institute of doobry" by searching "doobry institute" etc.

The problem I have is that I have lots of entries like "institute of doobry canteen" and "institute of doobry alumni association".

```
MATCH (names) AGAINST ("doobry institute")
```

will return all of these records and **will not score *institute of doobry* higher** than the canteen.

I'd sort of like to say: *score it higher if the word count is similar*.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Messy workaround answer:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM table
     WHERE MATCH ("doobdy institute") AGAINST (name)
  ORDER BY MATCH ("doobdy institute") AGAINST (name),
           ABS( LENGTH("doobdy institute") - LENGTH(name) )
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use a levenshtein function (not a default mysql funcion) as second orderby:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE MATCH("doobdy institute") AGAINST (name)
ORDER BY MATCH("doobdy institute") AGAINST (name) DESC, 
         levenshtein("doobdy institute", tag) ASC
```

this is a valid implementation of levenshtein algoritm in mysql:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671378/levenshtein-mysql-php

Comment: FULLTEXT searching, in itself, already throws the Query Optimizer "under the bus". Please don't add levenstein (Don't send a second bus. The dog is already mangled).

Comment: That looks genius but doesn't work brilliantly: `SELECT levenshtein("insitute doobry", "doobry institute canteen"), levenshtein("insitute doobry", "doobry institute");` Gives `15` and `15`. It works well in other situations.

Comment: this is how fulltext works:  since "institute" is not a stop word it has same weight of "doobry" in terms of match.

so you should decrease importance of  "institute" is some ways (for example stripping it before search,  or making another columns  where you strip your stop words like "institute"  then  remake a single fulltext key on both fields)